# QThreadPool: Is it ok to setExpiryTimeout(-1) or maybe I'm misusing the Threads?

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm experimenting with QThreadPool and realized that my program exited with SIGSEGV after QThreadPool reaches expiry timeout.

I started the program creating pointers to `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`s as placeholders, which are kept in `QList`s.

Then, the method `carregar2()` is called, when the menu is clicked, to start the QThreadPool.

I implemented 4 QRunnables. They're all the same: they invoke external program (QProcess) with different parameters. Their result are written to `QLineEdit`s.

If I set `setExpiryTimeout(-1)`, the program does not crash.

This is the `MainWindow` class, it is the called from the main.cpp :

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include "ClickableLabel.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QMainWindow::showMaximized();
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStringList args = QApplication::arguments();
    
    QString path;
    if(args.size()<=1)
        path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(parent, "", "/studio/FOTOS", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
    else
        path = static_cast<QString>(args.at(1));
    QDir *dir = new QDir(path);

    setWindowTitle("QExif - " + path);

    QScrollArea *scroll = new QScrollArea();
    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(scroll);
    QFrame *frame = new QFrame();

    int row=0;
    int col=0;

        QStringList filtro;
        filtro << "*.jpg";
        const QFileInfoList fil = dir->entryInfoList(filtro,QDir::Files );
        qDebug() << "FOTOS: " << fil.size();
        foreach (QFileInfo fi, fil ) {
            QString f = fi.absoluteFilePath();

            QLabel *l = new ClickableLabel();   //A custom QLabel that implements a clicked() signal and "emit clicked()" on mousePressEvent
            l->setStyleSheet("border: 5px solid white");
            l->setMaximumSize(w,h);
            l->setMinimumSize(w,h);
            l->setProperty("foto", f);
            l->setToolTip(f);
            connect(l, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(abrirVisualizadorExterno()));

            grid->addWidget(l,row,col,1,1,Qt::AlignTop);

            //tag buttons
            QHBoxLayout *box = new QHBoxLayout(parent);
            QFrame *btnFrame = new QFrame();
            btnFrame->setLayout(box);
            btnFrame->setMaximumWidth(w);

            QLineEdit *tagArtista = new QLineEdit(parent);
            tagArtista->setToolTip("Etiquetas");
            grid->addWidget(tagArtista,row+1,col,1,1,Qt::AlignTop);

            QLineEdit *tagDescricao = new QLineEdit(parent);
            tagDescricao->setToolTip("Descrição da imagem");
            grid->addWidget(tagDescricao,row+2,col,1,1,Qt::AlignTop);

            QLineEdit *tagDataHora = new QLineEdit(parent);
            tagDataHora->setToolTip("Data e Hora");
            grid->addWidget(tagDataHora,row+3,col,1,1,Qt::AlignTop);

            tagArtista->setProperty("foto", f);
            tagDescricao->setProperty("foto", f);
            tagDataHora->setProperty("foto", f);

            fList->append(f);
            labelList->append(l);
            tagList->append(tagArtista);
            descricaoList->append(tagDescricao);
            dataHoraList->append(tagDataHora);

            col++;
            if(col >3) { col=0; row+=4; }
        } //foreach

    frame->setLayout(grid);
    scroll->setWidget(frame);
    setCentralWidget(scroll);


    /*
     * MENU
     * */
    QMenu *menuExif = ui->menuBar->addMenu("Exif");
    menuExif->addAction("Carregar");
    connect(menuExif,SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)),this,SLOT(menuHandler(QAction*)));
}

void MainWindow::menuHandler(QAction *action){
    if(action->text() == "Carregar"){
        carregar2();
    }
}


void MainWindow::carregar2(){
    QThreadPool *pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    pool->setExpiryTimeout(-1);
    
    for(int i=0; i<fList->count(); i++){
        ImagemRunnable *imageRunnable = new ImagemRunnable(labelList->at(i), fList->at(i), w, h);
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(imageRunnable);

        TagRunnable *tagRunnable = new TagRunnable(tagList->at(i), fList->at(i));
        pool->start(tagRunnable);

        TagDescricaoRunnable *tagDescricaoRunnable = new TagDescricaoRunnable(descricaoList->at(i), fList->at(i));;
        pool->start(tagDescricaoRunnable);

        TagDataHoraRunnable *tagDataHoraRunnable = new TagDataHoraRunnable(dataHoraList->at(i), fList->at(i));
        pool->start(tagDataHoraRunnable);
    }
}

void MainWindow::abrirVisualizadorExterno(){
    ClickableLabel *l = (ClickableLabel *) sender();
    qDebug() << "Abrir" << l->property("foto");
    if (l->property("foto").isValid()){
        QStringList cmd;
        cmd << QString("eog %1").arg(l->property("foto").toString());
        system(cmd.at(0).toUtf8().data());
    }
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){

    qDebug() << watched->property("foto").toString();

    return false;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And this is one of the implemented `QRunnable`s:

header:

```
#ifndef TAGRUNNABLE_H
#define TAGRUNNABLE_H

#include <QRunnable>
#include <QLineEdit>

class TagRunnable : public QRunnable, QObject
{
public:
    TagRunnable(QLineEdit * f, QString file);
    void run() override;

private:
    QLineEdit *field;
    QString file;

};

#endif // TAGRUNNABLE_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "tagrunnable.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
TagRunnable::TagRunnable(QLineEdit * f, QString file)
{
    field = f;
    this->file = file;
}

void TagRunnable::run(){
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
    //pessoas na foto
    proc->start("/usr/bin/exif", QStringList()
                << "-t" << "0x013b"
                << "-m"
                << file
                );
    if(!proc->waitForFinished()){
        qDebug() << "Timeout ao ler exif tag (pessoas)." << file;
    }

    field->setText(proc->readAllStandardOutput());
    field->setProperty("tagOriginal", field->text());
}
```

My questions:

1. Suppose I use 30 seconds as expiry timeout. After that time, is my reference to the QProcess removed from memory and causing the QLineEdit text to be lost as well?
2. Is it ok to set expiry timeout to -1 in any situation or, perhaps, I'm not using it properly because of other architectural error of my program ?

Comment: First - you must not modify the GUI from outside the main thread but you do. Second - there is no reason to use threads at all here since QProcess is asynchronous.